# Adding date in filename of RollingFileAppender files

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Hi I am now using log4net for some time. This is my Logger:

```
public static class LoggerSetup
{
    private static RollingFileAppender _roller;
    private static PatternLayout _patternLayout;

    static LoggerSetup()
    {
        // root config
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;

        // prepare appender
        _roller = new RollingFileAppender();
        _patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        _roller.Layout = _patternLayout;


        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(_roller);

        _fileDirectory = "Log";
        Setup();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Location to save logfile
    /// </summary>
    public static string FileDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileDirectory;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileDirectory = value;
            Setup();

        }
    }
    private static string _fileDirectory;

    public static string DatePattern
    {
        get { return "_yyyy-MM-dd"; }
    }

    public static void Setup()
    {
        _roller.AppendToFile = true;
        _roller.File = FileDirectory + @"/" + "Log.log";
        _roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
        _roller.PreserveLogFileNameExtension = true;
        _roller.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
        _roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = -1; //--> Logger doesnt delete files himself
        _roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Composite;
        _roller.MaximumFileSize = "10KB";
        _roller.DatePattern = DatePattern;

        _patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%-5level] %message%newline";
        _patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        _roller.ActivateOptions();

    }
}
```

As you see, this Appender creates logfiles with maxsize 10K and it will also be rolled daily. This Configruation generates logfilenames as follows:

- *Log.log_2015-03-04*,
- *Log.1.log_2015-03-04*,
- *Log.2.log_2015-03-04*,
- *Log.log_2015-03-03*,
- *Log.1.log_2015-03-03*,
- *Log.2.log_2015-03-03*

**BUT** The today created logs look like this

- *Log.log*,
- *Log.1.log*,
- *Log.2.log*

What I want is that filenames look like this : *Log_yyyy-mm-dd_nr.log*

So how do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally done the following:

```
        _roller.DatePattern = "yyyy-mm-dd";
        _roller.PreserveLogFileNameExtension = true;
        _roller.File = Path.Combine(FileDirectory,".log");
        _roller.StaticLogFileName = false;
```

With those changes my log Files look like this:

- 2015-03-06.log         *the last one*
- 2015-03-06.1.log

Thanks everybody for the help

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have changed StaticLogFileName to true:

```
_roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
```

When using a date rolling style it should be false:

```
_roller.StaticLogFileName = false;
```

[[tips-on-using-log4net-rollingfileappender]](http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/tips-on-using-log4net-rollingfileappender.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should set StaticLogFileName to false, DatePattern to `_yyyy-MM-dd.log` and File to the path up to the date pattern, eg `Path.Combine(FileDirectory,"Log_")`:

```
_roller.File = Path.Combine(FileDirectory,"Log_");
_roller.StaticLogFileName = false;
_roller.DatePattern="_yyyy-MM-dd.log"
```

Comment: Thanks im going to try that

Comment: The Files i get with that configuration look like that *"Log__2015-03-06.loA.D..2"* - *"Log__yyyy-mm-dd.loA.D..nr"*.. Its almost correct, i don't get what's wrong with the extension